# Do perl, python or ruby run flawless flawless on 64bit system?

Tags: performance, 32bit-64bit, interpreter, internal, scripting-language

Do Perl, Python or Ruby run flawless on a 64bit Win7 system, or do you have to keep in mind pitfalls with integers and restriction on functions like I have read of on PHP?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for Perl and Python but Ruby works like a charm in my environment (at least, I never encountered any issue).

Answer (score 1):

Can say same as Matt about Activestate and strawberry perls, no issues encountered.